Coding and decoding byte array in string are not identical
I have to read a varbinary column from SQL Server, and send it to a json.
I tried some test conversions byte[]/string and vice-versa, but I cannot understand what is wrong.
For example:
string s = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString((byte[])value);
byte[] ba = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s);
bool f = ba.SequenceEqual((byte[])value); //false??? why??


Well is the byte array actually encoded text, using a UTF-16 encoding (which is what Encoding.Unicode represents)? If not, I'm not surprised it's losing information. It's like trying to load an mp3 as an JPEG file, save the resulting pixels, and then get the mp3 back. If you need to encode arbitrary binary data as text, you should use base64.

thank you, you are right! i posted solution

as @Jon Skeet suggests:
string s = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])value);
byte[] ba = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
bool f = ba.SequenceEqual((byte[])value); //true!!

